# How to design an cancellable API of plenty of I/O processes of a Java library?

Tags: java, multithreading

EDIT_2: The purpose of this question is

when the API is having more logics(ex: more I/O or network connection), we don't need to insert boolean flag condition inside those I/O or network logics to know it is canceled or not.

---

EDIT_1: I changed term **interrupt** with **cancel** to avoid confusion of thread's interrupt concept.

Sorry for misleading.

---

I have an existed API which has plenty of IO processes. For example

```
void heavyTask() {

    // Download File #1 with Network I/O
    HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient()
    ....
    ...
    ..
    while() {
        outputStream1.write()
    }

    // Save File #1 with File I/0 
    File file1 = new File();
    ....
    ...
    ..

    // Download File #2 with Network I/O
    HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient()
    ....
    ...
    ..
    while() {
        outputStream2.write()
    }

    // Save File #2 with File I/0 
    File file2 = new File();
    ...
    ..
}
```

My thought is to add cancel API by check cancelled flag inside
heavyTask()

```
volatile isCancelled = false; 

void cancelHeavyTask() {
    isCancelled = true;
}

void heavyTask() {

    // Download File #1 with Network I/O
    HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient()
    ....
    ...
    ..
    while() {
        outputStream1.write()
        if (isCancelled == true) // Add isCancelled flag
            return;
    }

    // Save File #1 with File I/0 
    File file1 = new File();
    ....
    ...
    ..
    if (isCancelled == true) // Add isCancelled flag
        return;

    // Download File #2 with Network I/O
    HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient()
    ....
    ...
    ..
    while() {
        outputStream2.write()
        if (isCancelled == true) // Add isCancelled flag
            return;
    }

    // Save File #2 with File I/0 
    File file2 = new File();
    ...
    ..
    if (isCancelled == true) // Add isCancelled flag
        return;
}
```

Currently the flag way works, but I can expect that **there will be more 'check flag conditions' when heavyTask is getting more complicated.**

I also thought make a specific worker thread to handle heavyTask,
and call **thread.interrupt()** of the worker thread when cancel is triggered.

However, after some investigations of Network I/O case, it seems like it still blocks while doing Network I/O process even thread.interrupt() triggered. Maybe thread.interrupt() is not a good way to implement.

Is there a concise and smart way to design a cancellable heavyTask API ?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably learn what [interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) really is. Your implementation is wrong.

Comment: There is no need to add that flag. I/O methods are generally interruptible (if they have been carefully designed). So if you run that `heavyTask` method in a separate thread and interrupt that thread, you will get the desired result out of the box.

Comment: On top of the above comment (that is `thread.interrupt()` does not really interrupt anything), you can benefit from operating on small chunks of data in each thread and breaking out when an interrupted state is attained between the chunks.

Comment: If your heavy task is doing blocking IO, and it is currently blocked, it will keep waiting for bytes to read, regardles of whether you set a boolean flag or not. Canceling blocking IO is typically done by closing the resource, and you'll get an IOException on the task thread.

Comment: Thanks for responses.
The purpose of this question is 
when the API is having more logics(ex: more I/O or network connection), we don't need to insert boolean flag condition inside those I/O or network logics to know it is canceled or not.